# ssh key login not working neither in Ubuntu nor CentOS 7

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I have read and watch lots of tutorials and I can't get it work.

In CentOS 7 I have done the following:

I have created the /.ssh folder with 700 in permissions and me as the owner

```
$ mkdir .ssh

$ chmod 700 .ssh/
```

Then I cd to it

```
$ cd .ssh
```

I proceeded to generate the key

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

I have chosen the passphrase

Then I created inside the `.ssh/` folder the authorized_keys file

```
$ nano authorized_keys
```

I pasted the content of id_rsa.pub inside of it.

Then I proceeded to edit the sshd_config

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And changed the following values

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

I saved and exited. I restarted sshd

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Then I downloaded both `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files to my local desktop computer.

I tried lots of times to connect via SSH using the [cmder software](http://cmder.net/) in Windows as follows:

```
λ ssh -i C:\Users\MyUsername\path\to\id_rsa.pub username@serverAddress
```

And the server indeed asks me for the passphrase but it is always wrong! It doesn't work and the it passes to the default username password login

:(

Why isn't the key passphrase not working? What am I missing in the set up???

I tried the same in Ubuntu and it is not working either.

Comment: Your question belongs to [su]. It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Okkeii. How do I move this question? `$ sudo mv thisquestion@stackoverflow thatquestion@superuser`

Comment: You cannot, once you accepted and upvoted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh -i C:\Users\MyUsername\path\to\id_rsa.pub username@serverAddress
```

Do you give `id_rsa.pub` to ssh command ? You have to give `id_rsa`, the secret key.

Comment: That did the trick. One more question, is it fine if I use ssh keys with different names? for example, `mySSHkey` and `mySSHkey.pub`? Or do I have to achieve some additional set up?

Comment: I think from security point of view, it is a good practice to use different SSH key according to the circumstance. In Linux and Mac, we can use `~/.ssh/config` to configure to use which username and secret key by hostname. I don't know about Windows.